# How to deploy from bitbucket directly to appfog?

Tags: git, deployment, web-deployment, bitbucket, appfog

I want my project to be automatically deployed to appfog when my bitbucket git repository is updated, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you have to do:

1. Setup and instance of [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) build server.
2. Configure Jenkins to pull from your Bitbucket repo, build and [deploy to Cloud
   Foundry](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2013/02/28/continuous-integration-to-cloud-foundry-com-using-jenkins-in-the-cloud/)
3. Configure [commit hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Configuring+commit+hooks) in your Bitbucket repository
   to execute your Jenkins build

Hope this helps

Comment: What should i set JENKINS_HOME environment variable to on AppFog?